How can I change the background color for TCheckBox in VCL?
I'm trying to change the background color of the TCheckBox in VCL through the Color property, but it's just not working for me.
I don't have any styles enabled. I've also tried playing with the properties and changing ones like ParentFont, ParentColor, StyledElements, etc... but nothing is making a different.
I'm just not able to change the background color on the TCheckBox.
What are the necessary properties and/or things to do in order for the Color property to work or to get the background color to change and be different?

You almost never want a checkbox to have a different background colour. In which scenario do you want this?

@AndreasRejbrand  I am using Checkboxes to let the user choose available colors and I need the checkbox background color to be the same color as what the checkbox change color would be. These checkboxes don't have a Caption. They want just the actual checkbox and then the background color.

Having no caption has the big disadvantage that one must click precisely on the check mark instead of having the caption as click area, too. And the focus can't be seen either. Why not simply using one or more full blocks ███? Not displaying the color name as text is also a handicap against color blind people.

As a member of these color blind group I suggest to use either a TColorBox or a TColorListBox.

Recent Windows versions (or better ComCtr32.dll) don't support coloring a checkbox. The only way to achieve that is to disable Runtime Themes in the project options under Manifest, but that has a lot of other drawbacks. You are basically mimicking the look before Windows XP.

You might be able to use an activation context to create just the CheckBox using a manifest which doesn't enable Comctrl32 v6, but I wasn't able to get it working cleanly, but that's probably just because of my lack of experience with the Activation Context API. Supposedly it is possible to use ComCtrl32 v5 and v6 in the same module/process.

If visual design is important for your project than it is time to create a custom style. Single style can have only one drawing color for checkbox, but your app can have multiple styles. So different checkboxes will use different styles and that way will have different colors. This is done like so:

Enable multiple styles in Project options > Appearance
Select one of them as default, but keep in mind that selecting standard windows style will disable styles engine
On your form set StyleName property of required controls to non default style


Like @Uwe pointed out:

Recent Windows versions (or better ComCtr32.dll) don't support coloring a checkbox


But I'd like to add a workaround solution for this at least that would allow you to have a different background color for the TCheckBox on recent versions of Windows.
If you need to have a different background color for the TCheckBox, then you can place it inside of a TPanel component and use the TPanel to display a background color for the TCheckBox.

And then start by setting the following properties:

Align to alClient on the TCheckBox
BevelOuter to bvNone on the TPanel

And then you can simply set the Color property on the TPanel and you'll have a TCheckBox with a different background color:

Here's my full DFM code for the above example:
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 441
  ClientWidth = 624
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  TextHeight = 15
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 24
    Top = 40
    Width = 153
    Height = 25
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clSkyBlue
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 5
      Top = 3
      Width = 145
      Height = 19
      Margins.Left = 5
      Align = alClient
      Caption = 'CheckBox1'
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = -27
      ExplicitTop = 19
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 24
    Top = 70
    Width = 153
    Height = 25
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clMoneyGreen
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 1
    object CheckBox2: TCheckBox
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 5
      Top = 3
      Width = 145
      Height = 19
      Margins.Left = 5
      Align = alClient
      Caption = 'CheckBox2'
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end


I'm pretty sure this depends on the Delphi/VCL version, too. Have you thought about color blind people who could be confused by this or even have difficulties to then read any text?
